# Words 2013 inserts whole object itself when caption is cross referenced

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, caption, cross-reference

I am inserting object -> Open Document Text

After I added the object, I added a caption by right-clicking the object and adding the caption. Everything is fine until now.

However, when I cross reference that caption, Word 2013 automatically inserts the entire object along with the caption itself, which is a completely undesired feature.

How can I prevent this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked the style of the object itself? If it's in a paragraph of the "Caption" style, Word will treat it as part of the caption.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck I did not check style how do i do that ? ty for answer

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck ty i may have found the error gonna test now

Comment: Word 2013 might be slightly different, but in 2010, it's in the Styles area of the Home tab. You click the arrow at the bottom right corner, and that brings up the Styles box.  In the Styles box, click the Style Inspector icon (a magnifying glass over a letter A). The Style Inspector box shows the paragraph style for the current selection.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck you were right the embeddings were also styled as caption i viewed source with alt f9 and made them normal ty very much. However below captions leaves 1 empty line between the caption and the object itself how can i fix that ?

Comment: That sounds like another style problem. Does the caption style include extra space below it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the style of the object is not Caption. Whatever is in the Caption style is treated as part of the caption.

Word 2013 might be slightly different, but in 2010, you can check this in the Styles area of the Home tab. You click the arrow at the bottom right corner, and that brings up the Styles box. In the Styles box, click the Style Inspector icon (a magnifying glass over a letter A). The Style Inspector box shows the paragraph style for the current selection.

If the object is in the Caption style, change it to another appropriate style (such as Normal) and update the Table of Contents (either by selecting it and clicking F9, or by right-clicking and selecting Update Field.